# How to calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{1+x+x^n} dx$?

Tags: integration, limits, analysis

How to calculate this limit?

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty }n\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{1+x+x^n} dx$

First method I tried this:

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)=(b-a)f(c)$.
So $f(c)=\frac{c^n}{1+c+c^n}$, but now i don't know in what range to fit f(c) to use Squeeze theorem.

Second method:

I tried to rewrite the integrate like this: $ \ln(3) - \int\limits_{0}^{1}\ln(1+x+x^n) dx -\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+x+x^n} dx$, but that doesn't get me anywhere.

Please help me and thanks for your time!

Comment: @CalvinKhor, I think your sign is backwards, the integrand is always smaller than 1 for non negative $x$.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @person oops. thanks!